# MySQL wildcard Like query with multiple words

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query as follows.

```
$query="SELECT name,activity FROM appid 
where result > 5 AND name LIKE :term ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0,40";

$result = $pdo->prepare($query);

$result->bindvalue(':term','%'.$_GET["q"].'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();
```

What i want to do is this.

I have and entry like this that i want to find

'News & Weather'

However when i type

'news weather'

it of course will not find it. How can i be able to type that and retrieve that entry?

Comment: Create an array of the words splitting on the space and have an `OR LIKE` for each value in the array.

Comment: Simpler: Use regular expressions (see answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) can do the trick:

```
select *
from appid
where name rlike 'news|weather' -- Matches 'news' or 'weather'
```

Another example:

```
select *
from appid
where name rlike 'news.*weather' -- Matches 'news' and 'wether' 
                                 -- with any characters in-between or none at all
                                 -- (ordered)
```

Just one more:

```
select *
from appid
where name rlike '^news.{1,}weather$' -- Matches any text that starts with 'news'
                                      -- and has at least one character before
                                      -- ending with 'weather'
```

Regular espressions can be used to create very complicated filters on text fields. Read the link above for more information.

---

If you can add a full-text index to your table, [Full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) might be the better way to go with this. Specifically, a [boolean Full-Text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

```
select *
from appid
where match(name) against (+news +weather)
```

Comment: This looks good but how to i implement this into my query that uses $_GET from user search?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way possible are through code:

Option A: Replace the spaces in your query parameter with '%' in code, but that of course will make the multiple words ordered

Option B: Split your parameter on spaces and dynamically construct your query with as many LIKEs as needed, adding additional ":termN" parameters for each one.

Comment: I recommend you read about [regular expressions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) for a better option

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot it has those; I don't really have a use for them in the data I regularly work with.

Comment: I said exactly the same when someone introduce them to me... and now I can't leave without them ;)

Comment: Most the time, I am searching for strings "starting with ABC" in indexed fields, so regex would be a detriment unless they've optimized it since the last time I checked so it can use an index when the expression begins with fixed text.